# Decrypt data within a node/express.js Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, cryptography

I have an app where I am trying to encrypt the `userID` before sending it to the client side. The reason for doing this is because I am using EJS as a tempting engine which means I have code where I am using the `userID` like so:

```
<body ng-init="getAllPosts('<%= user._id' %>)"></body>
```

The issue with this is that when someone does "inspect element" on any browser they can clearly see their `userID`. **See image below for example:**

[image]

To fix this issue I started Encrypting my `userID` before I sent to the client, like s0:

```
app.get('/profile',isLoggedIn,function(req, res) {

     var user = req.user;
     var uid = encrypt(JSON.stringify(user._id));

     res.render('profile.ejs', {
        userID: uid
    }); 
});
```

This Encrypts the ID successfully as you can see in the  image below:

[image]

**The Issue:**

The issue is that I can successfully Decrypt the ID but even after decrypted it I can't get the data from the database. I have tried copy pasting the decrypted ID into my route and that gets the data successfully. **Its like it does not read the decrypted ID from the variable but works when copy paste it myself.**

Heres the code:

```
app.get('/user/posts/:id', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){

        var x = decrypt(req.params.id)

        Posts.findOne({userID:x}, function(err, post){
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            else if(post){
                res.json(post);
            } else if(!post){
                res.json({message: "No Posts document exists for this user"});
            }    
        });
      });
```

**Thing to note is that the variable `x` contains decrypted ID is text form!**

Just for more info here are my Encrypting & Decrypting functions:

```
//Encrypt Data
 function encrypt(text){

  var cipher =  crypto.createCipher(algorithm,key)
  var crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64')
  crypted += cipher.final('base64');

  console.log("CRYPTED " + crypted);
  return crypted;
 }

//Decrypt Data
function decrypt(text){

 var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,key)
 var dec = decipher.update(text, 'base64', 'utf8')
 dec += decipher.final('utf8');

 console.log("DECRYPTED " + dec);
 return dec;
}
```

**Output of Decrypt Function:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, the problem was that I was being an idiot.

All I had to do to make is work was to change the following line from this:

```
Posts.findOne({userID:x})
```

**to**

```
Posts.findOne({userID: JSON.parse(x)})
```

The above solved the issue.